# Install SQL database in the drive where SQL Server is installed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, installation

```
CREATE DATABASE [JKamdar_Soft] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'JKamdar_Soft', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\JKamdar_Soft.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'JKamdar_Soft_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\JKamdar_Soft_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

I have these statements in database install file. In above example the OS is installed in C Drive. But we couldn't be sure in which drive the Client's Program Files folder would be. Is there any method in sql which says that "pls install database where OS is installed". Or any alternative method which makes sure the database is installed to correctd drive.

**Answer**

The above script sets a fix location to the  the SQL Database. We just need to remove the unnecessary lines in above script.
 We just need to write the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE [JKamdar_Soft]
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

And it automatically installes to the default instance of SQL Server.

Comment: That has nothing to do with where the OS is installed, its where SQL Server is installed.

Comment: @Jamiec: Yes my mistake, its where SQL server is installed.

Comment: Y everyone is closing the question ? Is the question invalid or do you dont have an answer to it

Comment: Put your answer as a real answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above script sets a fix location to the the SQL Database. We just need to remove the unnecessary lines in above script. We just need to write the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE [JKamdar_Soft]
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

And it automatically installes to the default instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Quibble - it doesn't install to the default instance of SQL Server - it installs to the default data file location of *whichever instance you're connected to*. If you've connected to a non-default instance, it will install on that instance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes you are right, the question is not correctly posed. I changed it now.